# DatagridView color controls not working on new form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid, desktop-application

I have a datagrid on main form. On cell click, I am creating a new form on which I am displaying a new data grid. On this new grid, i want to change background color of certain cell.

I have tried using :

```
  UnitData_DataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
```

but its not working.

Attached is the code:

```
     private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

               Form frm = new Form();                   

                DataGridView UnitData_DataGridView = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();


                Controls.Add(UnitData_DataGridView);
                frm.Controls.Add(UnitData_DataGridView);

                DataTable table = new DataTable();

                List<string[]> output = new List<string[]>();

                for (int i = 0; i < str.Count(); i++)
                {
                    table.Columns.Add(str[i]);

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {

                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                    for (int j = 0; j < strline.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        row[j] = strline[j];
                    }
                    table.Rows.Add(row);

                }

                UnitData_DataGridView.DataSource = table;
                UnitData_DataGridView.Size = new Size(1000, 500);
                UnitData_DataGridView.Enabled = true;
                UnitData_DataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
                UnitData_DataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in UnitData_DataGridView.Rows)
                {


                     if (row.Cells[8].Value.ToString() == "B")
                    {

                        UnitData_DataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.Brown;

                    }

                     if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().StartsWith("ERROR"))

                    UnitData_DataGridView.Rows[index].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                }


                frm.Location = new Point(0, 0);

                frm.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
                frm.AutoScroll = true;

                frm.Show();


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of issues with your code..:

The first of these lines is cancelled out by the second:

```
Controls.Add(UnitData_DataGridView);  // Remove!!
frm.Controls.Add(UnitData_DataGridView);
```

The first adds it to the current form. The second **moves** it to `Form frm`.

There **is** only **one** `DataGridView` and adding it to another `Controls` collection, removes it from the one it was in before..

You probably only want the second line.

- Another source of error is using the `CellContentClick`..: It only fires when there is actually content and you hit it.  If the cells are empty or if you don't need to actually hit the content do use the `CellClick` event instead..!

Depending on your needs you may or may not want to set

```
UnitData_DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

- You reference a row by a variable `index` but in the code you show this is not set.. **Maybe** you want to set it to `index = row.Index` ? But actually you already have the  `DataGridViewRow row` and could use it: `row.Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.Brown;`. But if you only want to refer to row 0, why not give it a nice and helpful name..:

  int rowOne = 0;
- Anyway, the real cause of the problem is a bit trickier: You are trying to change the looks of the `DataGridView` before is has even started to paint itself. Not sure why this should cause the problem, but it does.

For this to work, I found no better way than to change the order of events a little: Show the new form **before** painting the DGV!

There is no problem in keeping the initial size at zero, so you get no visual flicker..:

```
...
UnitData_DataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;

frm.Size = new Size(0,0);
frm.Show();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in UnitData_DataGridView.Rows)
{
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
frm.Location = new Point(0, 0);
frm.Size =  Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
frm.AutoScroll = true;
```

Yes, this is a **workaround**, but I found no more direct way; `Refreshing` or various `Invalidate` calls didn't help..

Maybe it would be a good idea to pull out the painting code into a function..

Comment: i want to change background color of certain cell of datagrid on my newly created form. But the implementation of the same is not working. It loads the new form but in default color .

even if I remove    Controls.Add(UnitData_DataGridView);  , the background color of specific cells are not changing.

Comment: Do your cells actually have some content?? If not it can't work Use the CellClick.. Did you use the debugger to see if the line where you set the color is actually hit??

Comment: I have checked for empty cell and in debugger  as well , it executes the lines which sets the color.

Answer (score 0):

To format the DataGridView cells, use the **CellFormatting** event.

This practice will allow you to sort or filter your datagridview, without reinitializing all cells formats.

```
 private void  UnitData_DataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex==8 && e.Value.ToString()=="B"               ) e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Brown ;
    if (e.ColumnIndex==3 && e.Value.ToString().StartsWith("ERROR")) e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i tried this , The background color of cells are changing now. but now i am getting " object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Some cell values may be null (no test because you didn't put any in your code). then add "&& e.value!=null" before "&& e.value.Tostring..." in both  tests